# PowerShell equivalent to bash's set -u

Tags: variables, powershell

Normally, bash replaces an undefined variable with an empty string:

```
$ echo "$BLAH things after blah"
 things after blah
```

But there's a handy way to change this behavior:

```
$ set -u
$ echo "$BLAH things after blah"
sh.exe": BLAH: unbound variable
```

(Pardon the `exe`. I'm running under MSYS bash.) I put this at the top of all my bash scripts. (Fail fast being a Good Thing and all that.)

PowerShell normally behaves the same way as bash:

```
PS C:\> echo "$blah things after blah"
 things after blah
```

My question: Is there any thing in PowerShell that changes this behavior so it will cause an error when I attempt to use an uninitialized variable?

Comment: In theory, `Set-PSDebug -Strict` does that, but it doesn't seem to work for string expansion. Hmmmm......

Comment: @TrevorSullivan The string interpolation is mostly just to make behavior consistent between the two commands. (bash trimmed off the space preceding "things" without it.) I would still like something that works for string interpolation, but that does help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that helped! Looks like someone else has an even better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
set-strictmode -version 2.0
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx

Comment: "Prohibits a variable without a name" Didn't even know that was possible. lol

Comment: Neither did I till this question was asked :)

Comment: We can now use `Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0` (compared to 2.0) to additionally "Prohibit out of bounds or unresolvable array indexes." which `set -u` does as well.